# Visual artifacts when rotating ShapeRenderer in libgdx

Tags: java, opengl-es, rotation, libgdx, artifacts

```
public void draw(ShapeRenderer renderer) {
    renderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    renderer.setColor(color);
    renderer.identity();
    renderer.translate(position.x, position.y, 0);
    renderer.rotate(0, 0, 1.0f, angle);
    renderer.ellipse(-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
    renderer.end();
}
```

[image: Artifact]

This is what I get with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this method:

```
public void ellipse(float x,
                    float y,
                    float width,
                    float height,
                    int segments)
```

because:

```
public void ellipse(float x,
                    float y,
                    float width,
                    float height)
```

will just call the first method and estimate the `segments` argument. Maybe this step was not optimized.

Comment: Source: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html#ellipse%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20int%29

Comment: Actually I've tried entering the number of segments by myself, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ok... this doesen't answer the original question, but my suggestion would be, that you could use a Texture with a white circle and then tint, scale and rotate it. ( I don't know weather this is more performance costly than using the shapeRenderer... )